# How to setup Sony S Tablet for Eclipse Debugging?

Tags: android

I have bought a Sony S tablet for development purpose but i'm having difficulties setting everything up.

I have enabled debugging on the tablet and installed adb driver, firt using the [official method](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/support-info.pl?info_id=878) and them the [automated method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1488822).

I have followed all the steps: setup,reboot etc... I have already run the echo method to setup the file C:\Users\user.androidadb_usb.ini with the 0x54c code. neither the versions work. I call adb devices and i see the following lines

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached

c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>
```

if i run my application on eclipse i get a windows to choose the device but no device is listed.

how can i install adb to be able to debug my application?

**Solution Found**

Yesterday i saw in the xda forum that we need to put the vendor id in the adb_usb.ini file. so i went to the path that was in the forum c:\users\user.android\adb_usb.ini. In this file i added the following entry 0x54c, that corresponds to Sony id. but nothings change.

Today i was looking for the google driver in my sdk file and i found that i have the same file in the sdk path. so i went to the previous changed file and copy the vendor id to this new file and now i can see the device on adb list and also on eclipse.

I hope i could help someone.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Your device has not correctly been installed on the PC. Check you have installed the correct driver for the Sony S Tablet, and try rebooting your PC and device.

Comment: How can i be sure that the correct driver is installed? on device manager it seems to be ok. Can you tell me how to validate the driver?

Comment: You will know if its installed correctly because it will appear in the Devices list under ADB or in eclipse, Have you enabled USB Debugging on the device?

Comment: yes i have enabled usb debugging on the device. as i said before it does't appear on eclipse and on ADB. can you tell me how to install it correctly?

Comment: Im afraid I dont have this device. I cannot offer any more info. I would advise you go to XDA-Developers and try and get some help from one of the developers there, who will have more experience with this.